# Add pop up on homepage in magento 2

Tags: magento2, home-page, popup

I want to show a message as a pop up on my homepage load with just a message, no email subscription, nothing.
I just want to display a message.
How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code in homepage

```
<div class="callfor-popup">
   <h2>Simple Modal</h2>
</div>
<script>
   require(
       [
           'jquery',
           'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
       ],
       function (
           $,
           modal
       ) {
           var modaloption = {
               type: 'popup',
               modalClass: 'modal-popup',
               responsive: true,
               innerScroll: true,
               clickableOverlay: true,
               title: 'Simple Modal'
           };
           var callforoption = modal(modaloption, $('.callfor-popup'));
           $('.callfor-popup').modal('openModal');
       }
   );
</script>
```

Comment: where to add a message? and where to add this code? in which file?

Comment: You want to add in cmspage, phtml file. "Simple Modal" is your content

Comment: which cms page?

Comment: content > pages > select your "Home Page" and add this code.

Answer (score 1):

create module and add 2 file from your side

**1. app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml**

**2. app/code/Vendor/Module/registration.php**

**3. app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/ModalOverlay.php**

```
    namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

use Magento\Cms\Api\BlockRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Cms\Api\Data\BlockInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

class ModalOverlay extends Template
{

    private $blockRepository;

    public function __construct(
        BlockRepositoryInterface $blockRepository,
        Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->blockRepository = $blockRepository;

        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getContent($identifier)
    {
        try {
            /** @var BlockInterface $block */
            $block = $this->blockRepository->getById($identifier);
            $content = $block->getContent();
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            $content = false;
        }

        return $content;
    }
}
```

**4. app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/modal_overlay.phtml**

```
<?php if ($content = $block->getContent('any-cms-block-indetifier-to-be-displayed')) { ?>

    <div id="modal-overlay" style="display:none;">
        <?php echo $content ?>
    </div>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "*": {
                "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                    "components": {
                        "modal_overlay": {
                            "component": "Vendor_Module/js/modal_overlay"
                        }
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    </script><?php } ?>
```

**5. app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\ModalOverlay"
                   template="Vendor_Module::modal_overlay.phtml"
                   name="modalOverlay"
                   as="modalOverlay"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**6. app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/modal_overlay.js**

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function (Component, $, modal, storage) {
    'use strict';

    var cacheKey = 'modal-overlay';

    var getData = function () {
        return storage.get(cacheKey)();
    };

    var saveData = function (data) {
        storage.set(cacheKey, data);
    };

    if ($.isEmptyObject(getData())) {
        var modal_overlay = {
            'modal_overlay': false
        };
        saveData(modal_overlay);
    }

    return Component.extend({

        initialize: function () {

            this._super();
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: false,
                title: false,
                buttons: false
            };

            var modal_overlay_element = $('#modal-overlay');
            var popup = modal(options, modal_overlay_element);

            modal_overlay_element.css("display", "block");

            this.openModalOverlayModal();

        },

        openModalOverlayModal:function(){
            var modalContainer = $("#modal-overlay");

            if(this.getModalOverlay()) {
               return false;
            }
            this.setModalOverlay(true);
            modalContainer.modal('openModal');
        },

        setModalOverlay: function (data) {
            var obj = getData();
            obj.modal_overlay = data;
            saveData(obj);
        },

        getModalOverlay: function () {
            return getData().modal_overlay;
        }

    });
});
```

Hopefully, it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Magento have alert widget to show messages as alert. please check
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_alert.html

```
require([
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/alert',
    'jquery'
], function(alert, $) { // Variable that represents the `alert` function

    alert({
        title: $.mage.__('Some title'),
        content: $.mage.__('Some content'),
        actions: {
            always: function(){}
        }
    });

});
```

To add this into your home page, you have many option

**Option 1**

Edit Home Page Content from `Content > Elements > Pages` select your home page and edit then add it between `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` block inside the page content
[image]

**Option 2**
add static block with the above code from `Content > Elements > Blocks`
then add it to the home page via a widget from `Content > Widgets` and add new widget then select your theme and static block type
[image]

Then apply these configuration to add it to your homepage and use widget options to select the static block you created

[image]

**Option 3**

From `Content > Design > Configuration` Edit the store view configuration you want and add this content in the Footer section in  **Miscellaneous HTML** and hit save. clean your cache and it will appear

Comment: what do i need to do to show it on homepage load

Comment: Please check the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout**

**cms_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test" template="VendoreName_ModuleName::popup.phtml"></block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates**

**popup.phtml**

```
<div id="popup" style="display: none;">
   <h2>Your massage</h2>
</div>
<script>
   require(
       [
           'jquery',
           'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
       ],
       function (
           $,
           modal
       ) {
           var modaloption = {
               type: 'popup',
               modalClass: 'my-popup',
               responsive: true,
               innerScroll: true,
               title: 'My Modal',
               buttons: []
           };
           var callforoption = modal(modaloption, $('#popup'));
           $('#popup').modal('openModal');
       }
   );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

create popup.phtml

```
<div id="promotional-popup" class="white-popup-block mfp-hide">
        <div class="popup-wrap">
            <?php if($popupData->getBanner()) { ?>
            <a href="<?= $popupData->getUrl() ? $popupData->getUrl() : '#' ?> ">
                <div class="popup-img">
                    <img src="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $this->getBaseMediaUrl() . $popupData->getBanner(); ?>" />
                </div>
            </a>
            <?php } ?>
            <div class="popup-content"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $popupData->getContent(); ?></div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "*": {
                "Namespace_Popup/js/promotional" : {}
            }
        }
    </script>
```

create promotional.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'MagnificPopup',
    'mage/mage'
], function ($) {
    return function (config) {
        $('#newsletter-popup-form').mage('validation', {});
        $.magnificPopup.open({
            items: {
                src: '#promotional-popup',
            },
            closeOnContentClick: false,
            closeOnBgClick: true,
            enableEscapeKey: false,
            type: 'inline',
            closeBtnInside: true,
        }, 0);
    }
})
```